# How to use Output as a link and replacement patterns to get friendly URLs

Tags: 7, views, path-aliases

In a View, with a list of fields, I have the **Rewrite results --> Output this field as a link**, and a replacement pattern **[title]**. However, the URL is not completely friendly, although I can substitute white space for dashes **"-"**, it still can have accents or other symbols which simply do not appear when using the module [PathAuto](https://www.drupal.org/project/pathauto) and the function ´pathauto_cleanstring´ in which they are substituted. As the links are completely dynamical, I cannot find any option in the Config of the module to have the patterns substituted.

Summarizing, I have a field "title", and I get the output rewrite as

```
my-page/[title]
```

if I have a node titled "Atención: no beber", I would like to have the URL:

```
my-page/atencion-no-beber
```

and I am getting, instead,

```
my-page/Atención:-no-beber
```

The only way I have found is programmaticaly rewriting the output again, but I am confident that it can be done without a single line of code somehow.

How can output this URL without programmatically rewriting it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly, it sounds like you're trying to redo the aliasing work PathAuto does in Views.

If that's the case, you can add a *Content: Path* field to your view (using the **Exclude from display** option if you don't want it visible) and use `[path]` in your link output to link it to your pathauto alias.

Comment: Yes, that is a working solution, but I cannot control the output of [path] as it is quite automatic. In my specific case, I have a content type which is a product, a field which is a reference number (unique) and a name. I want to have a URL like product/[ref_number]-[name]. I am not sure if this can be matched to the automatic [path] somehow (in Alias URL patterns or something).